# Selecting all values if nothing is selected from drop-down list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a from by which I generate data after submitting the drop-down values of form to another page.

```
<form method="post" action="details.php">

<select name="Station">
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Home">Home</option>
<option value="Office">Office</option>
</select>

<select name="Section">
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Living">Living Room</option>
<option value="Dinning">Dinning Room</option>
<option value="Bathroom">Bathroom</option>
</select>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Based on the above form I have **Station** and **Section** Columns in a MySQL database with the values that I mentioned.

It works fine if I select *Home* from **Station** and *Bathroom* from **Section**, But if I select *All* from **Station** and *Bathroom* from **Section** then I get an error because I don't have a record with the value **All**  in column named **Station**. Instead I have records with values *Home* and *Office* (by *All* I mean that both *Home* and *Office* should be generated).

My question is how to generate details of both stations when I select *All* from drop-down list.

In my details.php page I have:

```
$execItems = $conn->query("SELECT StationName, SectionName FROM profiles WHERE Station = '$Station' AND Section = '$Section'");
```

It works fine if I select *Home* or *Office* from **Station**, but if I select *All* from **Station** then it won't work because there is no value by the name of *All* in **Station** column (By *All* I meant that both *Home* and *Office* should be selected.).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks, I am using this just for learning purposes for now afterward i will use them. By the way do you know any solution for my question. :)

Comment: Only include the where clause if values are provided

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry. Can you give me a clue.

Comment: Strawberry did give you a clue. With empty values for the two dropdowns, the SQL statement would be ```SELECT StationName, SectionName FROM profiles WHERE Station = '' AND Section = ''``` If there isn't a value, don't test for it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @SloanThrasher ok i changed the value of All from drop-down to empty, and now when i select all and hit the submit button still i don't receive any data.

SELECT StationName, SectionName FROM profiles WHERE Station = '' AND Section = ''

The result is blank.

Comment: You could store your WHERE statement in another variable and concatenate (or not) depending on the value chosen. You could also do something like `WHERE (station = '$Station' OR '$Station' = 'ALL') AND  (Section = '$Section' OR '$Section' = 'ALL')`. There's a few ways to skin this cat in both php and your sql.

Comment: @JNevill i don't have any data with ALL. I just have Home and Office in Station and i want that if none of them where selected and then both Home and Office data should be loaded.

Comment: you need dynamic where clause  based on input is empty or not

Comment: @JYoThI, can you help me to write it as sql statement

Comment: try my below answer @Ahmad

Answer (score 1):

While a dynamically written WHERE clause would be a better way to go, a quick fix is to adjust the WHERE clause to account for `ALL` being passed in from the form.

```
WHERE (station = '$Station' OR '$Station' = 'ALL') AND (Section = '$Section' OR '$Section' = 'ALL')
```

If someone is to choose, for `station` the form value `ALL` and the value `Dining` for the `Section` form, then this WHERE clause becomes:

```
WHERE (station = 'ALL' or 'ALL' = 'ALL') AND (Section = 'Dining' or 'Dining' = All)
```

That first OR will generate a `TRUE` because `'All' = 'All'` and the second will return `TRUE` in the event that the record being tested has a `section` value of `Dining`.

Comment: There is no `All` value in `Station` column to retrieve data like: `SELECT StationName From profiles WHERE Station = 'All'` Instead i have `Home` and `Office` values, so i need that when `All` is selected from drop-down then both `Home` and `Office` row should be retrieved.

Comment: I've updated this answer to better explain what I was talking about in the comments. It's a little odd to be passing in hard coded values for testing by the database, which is why a dynamically generated statement is a better choice, but this will suffice as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to build  `dynamic where clause` based on input  like this

```
<?php

 $where ="1=1";

 if(isset($_POST['Station']) && !empty($_POST['Station']) && $_POST['Station'] !='All')
  {
      $where .=" and station = '$Station'";
  }

  if(isset($_POST['Section']) && !empty($_POST['Section']) && $_POST['Section'] !='All')
  {
      $where .=" and  section= '$section'";
  }

  "SELECT StationName, SectionName FROM profiles WHERE".$where
```

Comment: I used it like this : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4sgh3co4/) but i got error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in line 93` which is `while($infoItems = $execItems->fetch_array()){`

Comment: echo "SELECT Station, Section FROM profiles WHERE".$where;   exit; do like this before execute  to know the error in your query  @Ahmad